# How to use assets in open shift rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, openshift

I was deploying my code in openshift rails but it did not take the assets properly.
It's neither loading the javascripts nor the images.
How to make it work?

Comment: did you ran the command `rake assets:precompile` before starting the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you will want to check is if the assets exist on your application. [This script](https://github.com/openshift/rails-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_build) is run before the `build.sh` script (mentioned next). It attempts to create a symlink for your `public/assets` folder ([here is the reasoning behind this](https://github.com/openshift/rails-example#assets)). Even if you had that directory, the `rake` task would still work; the assets would just be wiped every push.

Your assets should be compiling whenever you push to your git repository. This is taken care of by [this script](https://github.com/openshift/crankcase/blob/master/cartridges/ruby-1.9/info/bin/build.sh#L45) in the Ruby 1.9 cartridge (this is run by the service and you have no control over it). As you can see, it will run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` as long as you have a Gemfile (which should be the case for all Rails apps).

With all that being said, the first thing you should do is check your `.openshift/action_hooks` to make sure you are not running anything that might be overwriting your `public/assets` directory. You can compare them against the ones [here](https://github.com/openshift/rails-example/tree/master/.openshift/action_hooks).

The next thing you should do is actually check the directory on your OpenShift host. You can do this by SSHing into your app ([instructions are here](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/remote-access)). Then check your `public/assets` directory. Note: Some of the output has been shortened with `....`.

```
# First we make sure it is a symlink.
> file $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/public/assets
..../app-root/runtime/repo/public/assets: symbolic link to `..../data//assets'

# Then we see if there is anything in it
> ls $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/public/assets
.... (should have a bunch of.js, .css, etc files)
```

If that directory is empty, maybe there is a problem with compiling the assets. You should pay attention to the output when you `git push` and see if there is any indication that it is failing (you may want to capture the output using `tee` like: `git push 2>&1 | tee git_push.log`). If there are assets in the directory, check your logs by following [these steps](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/faq/how-to-debug-application-issues-using-logs).

If you're still having problems, swing by our [IRC channel](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/developers/get-help) and somebody should be able to help in person.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer :) I wish I could give more up votes :)